# Select XML from list of XML only if the Child elements tags values are matched

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, notepad++, extract, parent

For the Given List of XML

```
<ns:Input>
<ns:location>asfsafs</ns:location>
<ns:locationevent>xxxx</ns:locationevent>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>abc</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>ghy</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
<ns:Coverage>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>deg</ns:name>
</ns:Action>>
</ns:Coverage>
<ns:ID>12133</ns:ID>
</ns:Input>

<ns:Input>
<ns:location>asfsafs</ns:location>
<ns:locationevent>yyyy</ns:locationevent>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>abc</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>def</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
<ns:Coverage>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>def</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
</ns:Coverage>
<ns:ID>12233</ns:ID>
</ns:Input>

<ns:Input>
<ns:location>asfsafs</ns:location>
<ns:locationevent>yyyy</ns:locationevent>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>abc</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>def</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
<ns:Coverage>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>def</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
</ns:Coverage>
<ns:ID>1423</ns:ID>
</ns:Input>


<ns:Input>
<ns:location>asfsafs</ns:location>
<ns:locationevent>xxxx</ns:locationevent>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>abc</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>ghy</ns:name>
</ns:Action>
<ns:Coverage>
<ns:Action>
<ns:name>deg</ns:name>
</ns:Action>>
</ns:Coverage>
<ns:ID>12</ns:ID>
</ns:Input>
```

I want to pick only the XML which is matching the following conditions

```
<ns:Input>..<ns:locationevent>yyyy</ns:locationevent>..<ns:Action>..<ns:name>def</ns:name>..
<ns:Input>..<ns:Coverage>..<ns:Action>..<ns:name>def</ns:name>..<ns:ID>1423</ns:ID>..</ns:Input>
```

If use the following command in Notepad++,

```
<ns:Input>(?:(?!</ns:Input>).)*<ns:locationevent>yyyy</ns:locationevent.*?<ns:Action>.*? 
<ns:name>def</ns:name>.*?<ns:Coverage>.*?<ns:Action>.*?<ns:name>def</ns:name>(?:(?!</ns:Input>).)* 
 (1423).*?</ns:Input>
```

It picks both 2nd and 3rd XMLs. It should have picked only 3rd XML which is matching the above conditions.

Can you help?
This should be accomplished in Notepad++ regex.

Comment: This is no job for regex; you should try something like xpath. Also, what exactly is your desired output?

Comment: I mentioned in  the post that I need only 3td XML from the list of XML, if I Use the above command.

Comment: I have no idea what "3td XML from the list of XML" is; please edit your question and post **exactly** what that desired output looks like.

Comment: I need the below XML as output

    <ns:Input>
    <ns:location>asfsafs</ns:location>
    <ns:locationevent>yyyy</ns:locationevent>
    <ns:Action>
    <ns:name>abc</ns:name>
    </ns:Action>
    <ns:Action>
    <ns:name>def</ns:name>
    </ns:Action>
    <ns:Coverage>
    <ns:Action>
    <ns:name>def</ns:name>
    </ns:Action>
    </ns:Coverage>
    <ns:ID>1423</ns:ID>
    </ns:Input>
 
    which matches the following conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Add the XML Tools plugin in Notepad++, evaluate the following xpath expression and see if it works:

```
//ns:Input[//ns:name[text()='def']][ns:locationevent[text()='yyyy']][ns:ID[text()='1423']]
```

Comment: Try wrapping your xml above with `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc xmlns:ns="http://www.example">` at the top and `</doc>` see if that works for you.

Comment: It didnt work. Can you place and explain it in a screenshot